# Resources to integrate ESRI gis to SAP ?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-platform, integration, sap

I heard to this term to integrate GIS with SAP.What does this actually mean? Where can i find resources to integrate GIS to SAP. I have no idea on where to start and to proceed further?

Answer (score 4):

You can find a lot of information on esri.com
Here are some. Even if some documents are not brand new, they have helped me to understand how a GIS SAP integration could work.

---

http://www.esri.com/partners/alliances/sap

[image]

---

Some Best Practices examples: http://www.esri.com/~/media/Files/Pdfs/library/bestpractices/using-gis-and-sap.pdf

[image]

---

ArcNews article: http://www.esri.com/news/arcnews/spring09articles/integrating-gis.html

[image]

---

A Powerpoint presentation: http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/egug2006/papers/sap-integration.pdf

[image]